# Data Sync between tables from SQL Server & Db2 - how to delete rows

Tags: sql-server, db2

We have two databases one in SQL Server & one in DB2, we have a scenario where we do some data inserts & data updates and deletes in SQL Server & at the same time we also do data inserts updates & deletes in Db2.

We sync data back & forth using some processes, whenever there is a change from SQL Server we sync data to db2 for insert, update & delete, if we have a change in db2 we sync data to SQL Server, we use IBM MQ messages which we dequeue the messages to sync the changes back and forth.

Everything was good until we had some issues of data sync from Db2 to SQL Server, one of our process was down which sync from db2 to SQL Server, so there is an on demand job that runs every night that will do full data refresh from Db2 to SQL Server but we are only doing Merge Update & insert, we are not doing delete as data which is yet to be synced to db2 is also present in SQL Server, so we cannot directly delete as both databases can have more or less records, so data on SQL Server some of them are left orphan, we have a scoping so data which is getting updated in SQL Server cannot be change in db2 and vice versa.

My question is when we are syncing from Db2 to SQL Server, how to identify records that got deleted from db2 only so that we can delete those from SQL Server, we don't want to delete records that are created in SQL Server but yet to be sent to db2, we have 114 tables and we cannot maintain a flag if that is an option to differentiate.

Comment: It sounds like you're _manually_ syncing updates between the systems, both of which are being treated as master data.  This has the potential to go **more** wrong, frankly.  Personally, I'd probably make one side "master", and set up [replication](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/replication/non-sql/ibm-db2-subscribers?view=sql-server-ver15), then have the other side push updates to master via `INSTEAD OF` triggers, and wait for the data to filter back to the synced table, which should be more stable.

Comment: We have two databases one in SQL Server& existing Db2(Mainframes) which is a legacy system. How can we create replication for two different databases in SQL & Db2?, so to fix this we are sending IBM MQ messages and each side is consuming those messages to sync the changes in either systems.DB2 to an extent is like master and SQL has less tables which is scoped for phase 1,the process to load the changes from db2 to sql is broken and we have on demand that refreshes full db by copying to staging tables to SQL,here we can't delete in sql as we may lose data which is yet to be sent to DB2, how ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for the suggestions, I am not using CDC, but maintaining changes in a LOG table which are yet to be synced to DB2.

```
DELETE TGT
   FROM [IGP].[LocationType] AS TGT
   INNER JOIN #locationType SRC ON 
   TGT.[LocationTypeCode] = SRC.[LocationTypeCode];
```

I am first inserting the log table data that are yet to be synced to DB2 into #locationType temp table and delete them from IGP(staging Db2 master data) so the updates & Deletes won't be overridden from IGP staging table data which is Db2 master data.

Now I need to take care of inserts that don't exists in Db2 and there in SQL server but it's not synced from the log table I shouldn't be deleting them as it would be data loss, so I use below merge query

```
 MERGE INTO [dbo].[LocationType] AS TGT
  USING [IGP].[LocationType] AS SRC
  ON TGT.[LocationTypeCode] = SRC.[LocationTypeCode]
  WHEN MATCHED  AND (EXISTS 
  (SELECT TGT.[Description] EXCEPT SELECT SRC.[Description]))  
  THEN
    UPDATE SET TGT.[LocationTypeCode] = SRC.[LocationTypeCode], 
    TGT.[Description] = SRC.[Description]
  WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
  INSERT([LocationTypeCode], [Description]) 
  VALUES([LocationTypeCode], [Description]) 
  WHEN NOT MATCHED BY SOURCE 
  AND (EXISTS (SELECT TGT.[LocationTypeCode] 
      EXCEPT SELECT [LocationTypeCode] FROM #locationType)) THEN DELETE;
```

Answer (score 3):

When you said you are synchronizing data back and forth between MS SQL Server and DB2 Server, how are you capturing the changes?  If using some CDC tool (IDR, GoldenGate, Informatica), these tools allow you to detect conflicts so you can decide what records to keep or delete.

If you are capturing your changes by an in-house development (triggers or your own log **scraper** ), you should keep at least the operation type and timestamp in your temporary change data set, so that you can recognize the operation.

If you are comparing the tables and deal with changes, you won't be able to recognize if missing columns at DB2 side represents rows deleted on DB2 side or rows added to SQL side... But you can fix that, by developing a proper change data capture mechanism.

Answer (score 2):

[Change tracking](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/track-changes/about-change-tracking-sql-server) on the sql server side might be a viable option (as long as all the tables you would like to sync/"delete from" have a primary key).

With CT you could track which rows, for each table, were created at the sql server side 
since the last sync from sql server to db2. Those rows should not be deleted yet:

```
DELETE 
FROM SQL_SERVER_TABLE
WHERE
  NOT EXISTS(SELECT * FROM CHANGETABLE())
  AND NOT EXISTS(SELECT * FROM DB2_staging)
```

Answer (score 2):

I would connect SQL to DB2 via linked servers (more there : https://learn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/sql/relational-databases/system-stored-procedures/sp-addlinkedserver-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) and then do queries to find out which record are missing on both sides.
This can be accomplished with OPENQUERY. You can do something like that :

```
SELECT * FROM YourSqlTable
EXCEPT 
SELECT * FROM OPENQUERY(YOURDB2SERVER, 'SELECT * FROM YourDB2Table')
```

And then the same thing inverted :

```
SELECT * FROM OPENQUERY(YOURDB2SERVER, 'SELECT * FROM YourDB2Table')
EXCEPT 
SELECT * FROM YourSqlTable
```

You can then send the records on the right server .

If you have a lot of tables to compare you can write these queries with dynamic SQL

```
DECLARE @TABLENAME nvarchar(200);
DECLARE TABLE_CUR CURSOR FOR
     SELECT TABLE_NAME FROM YourDatabaseName.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES;

OPEN TABLE_CUR 
FETCH NEXT FROM TABLE_CUR INTO @TABLENAME;

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0  
BEGIN  
    DECLARE @Query nvarchar(MAX);
    SET @Query =  'SELECT * FROM OPENQUERY(YOURDB2SERVER, ''SELECT * 
                   FROM '+ @TABLENAME + ' '')
                   EXCEPT 
                   SELECT * FROM '+ @TABLENAME 

    -- Don't forget the double '' for openquery

    EXEC sp_executeSQL @Query;

    SET @Query =  'SELECT * FROM '+ @TABLENAME + ' 
                   EXCEPT
                   SELECT * FROM OPENQUERY(YOURDB2SERVER, ''SELECT * 
                   FROM '+ @TABLENAME + ' '')'
    -- Don't forget the double '' for openquery

    EXEC sp_executeSQL @Query;
END
CLOSE TABLE_CUR;  
DEALLOCATE TABLE_CUR;
```